# Expected value of a sum of random events

Tags: probability, random

Suppose there's a market that has decided to award its most loyal customers. The market sells a certain type of breakfast cereals with a single token in each box. There are ***n*** different **types** of tokens. During production of each box, a token is chosen at random and placed in the box. In order to be awarded a prize, one must collect all different tokens. If each box of cereal costs ***x*** dollars, what is the expected amount of money (in terms of ***x***) one would have to pay in order to win the prize?

Comment: Hint: [Coupon Collector's Problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coupon_collector%27s_problem#solution)

Comment: So, according to that, the answer would be ~ n*log(n) * x ?

Comment: For small $n$ it would be better to use: $E[N]= n H_n = n\sum_{k=1}^n k^{-1}$ and evaluate the sum rather than approximating.

Comment: All right, but can you tell me why you omitted the ***x*** in your formula?

Comment: It's a constant.  $E[xN] = xE[N]$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $X_{k}$ denote the number of boxes that are to be bought to come in possession of $k+1$ tokens, counting from the moment that one is in possession of exactly $k$ different
tokens.

Then $X=1+X_{1}+\cdots+X_{n-1}$ boxes must be bought.

Here $X_{k}$
has geometric distribution with parameter $p_{k}=1-\frac{k}{n}$ so that
$\mathbb{E}X_{k}=\frac{1}{p_{k}}=\frac{n}{n-k}$.

We find $\mathbb{E}X=\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\frac{n}{n-k}=n\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{k}$

The expected amount of money to be paid is $nx\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{k}$.

Comment: How did you find the parameter p?

Comment: If exactly $k$ distinct tokens are in your possession then $n-k$ tokens (those not yet in your possession) are still interesting for you. If you buy a box then the chance that it contains one of these interesting tokens (that adds $1$ to the number of tokens in possession) is $\frac{n-k}{n}$